# Copying Relational Table Data

Tags: mysql, database, performance, grails, relational-database

I hope I'm not being too long winded in this question, I just want to make sure that what I'm asking is completely clear (I think it's rather confusing :).

I've got a database with a bunch of tables with all my foreign key constraints set up. Relations are sometimes several tables deep, and there are also cases where a child is related to more than one parent table. I want to insert a copy of one of my "top level" table rows, and all of child table data that relates to it (keeping the relational integrity). That is to say my new top level row gets its own new primary key (via auto_increment), and all the new child rows get their own primary keys (again through auto_increment), and all the foreign key information of the tables relates analogously to the data I copied (only now with the newly created primary keys). So now I would have a copy of the relational data that was independently mutable from the original.

To make my example more concrete, I have painstakingly set up an analogous, but simpler example. Lets define the following tables:

[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/ef22070a89.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/ef22070a89.png)

All the green id fields are auto_update primary keys, and the yellowish ones are indexed columns with foreign key constraints. Lets say the database has the following data in it initially:

```
job_types
+----+----------+
| id | jobcode  |
+----+----------+
|  1 | DEADBEEF |
|  3 | FEEDFACE |
+----+----------+

managers
+----+---------------+-------------+
| id | name          | job_type_id |
+----+---------------+-------------+
|  1 | John          |           1 |
|  3 | Michael Scott |           3 |
+----+---------------+-------------+

departments
+----+------+------------+
| id | name | manager_id |
+----+------+------------+
|  1 | H32  |          1 |
|  2 | X11  |          3 |
+----+------+------------+

employees
+----+-------------+---------------+------------+-------------+
| id | name        | department_id | manager_id | job_type_id |
+----+-------------+---------------+------------+-------------+
|  1 | Billy Bob   |             1 |          1 |           1 |
|  2 | Sandra Lee  |             1 |          1 |           3 |
|  3 | Buddy Holly |             2 |          3 |           1 |
+----+-------------+---------------+------------+-------------+
```

Now say what I want to do is make a relational copy of department H32 (id=1).

What I should end up with is something like the following (obviously actual values of primary keys is not important, referential integrity is).

```
job_types
+----+----------+
| id | jobcode  |
+----+----------+
|  1 | DEADBEEF |
|  3 | FEEDFACE |
|  4 | DEADBEEF |
|  5 | FEEDFACE |
+----+----------+

managers
+----+---------------+-------------+
| id | name          | job_type_id |
+----+---------------+-------------+
|  1 | John          |           1 |
|  3 | Michael Scott |           3 |
|  4 | John          |           4 |
+----+---------------+-------------+

departments
+----+------+------------+
| id | name | manager_id |
+----+------+------------+
|  1 | H32  |          1 |
|  2 | X11  |          3 |
|  3 | H32  |          4 |
+----+------+------------+

employees
+----+-------------+---------------+------------+-------------+
| id | name        | department_id | manager_id | job_type_id |
+----+-------------+---------------+------------+-------------+
|  1 | Billy Bob   |             1 |          1 |           1 |
|  2 | Sandra Lee  |             1 |          1 |           3 |
|  3 | Buddy Holly |             2 |          3 |           1 |
|  4 | Billy Bob   |             3 |          4 |           4 |
|  5 | Sandra Lee  |             3 |          4 |           5 |
+----+-------------+---------------+------------+-------------+
```

What's the most efficiently performing way to implement this type of copy operation? For what it's worth I'm working with MySQL, using the InnoDB table engine, in the context of Grails. I'm looking forward to hearing some good ideas on how you do something like this "the right way."

-- Regards, Vic

I've posted [a MySQLDump of the example](http://pastebin.com/v0RG0AJV) initialization on PasteBin.

**EDIT**
For what it's worth, I posted a much simpler / broader question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3260091/databases-and-deep-copy/3260254#3260254) and I got generally positive responses, suggesting that I'm not "just doing it wrong"...

Comment: If I may ask, what's your motivation for making copies down the entire table graph?  Your question is making data anomaly alarms go off in my head.

Comment: @proflux, agreed, it almost seems as if the data is being denormalized by doing a deep copy

Comment: Alarms running here too.

Comment: Removed my answer because I missed that you also want to have employees duplicate it's rows.  I know throw my hat into the "why would you wan to do that" ring.

Comment: @proflux, Lets say you had a system that had a relational model. If departments was the root of the relational structure, and i wanted to create a new department that was absolutely a separate instance of a department, but had the same initial structure as department H32 in my example, it seems to me a deep copy is the way to do it. It's still normalized, but I am now free to alter the copy without affecting the original... why does this seem odd to you? If I'm thinking about it wrong, how should I be thinking about it differently?

Comment: @proflux, also this is a contrived example, but my tables represent a complex relational object that gets built up by a user through a UI, the deep copy operation seems like a necessary step as a shortcut to provide an initial object to the user based on an existing object in the database.

Comment: @Mark, I would contend that a set of tables either is or is not normalized... you can't do something after the structure exists to "denormalize" the database...

Comment: @illarra, care to go into some detail on what alarms you are thinking?

Comment: @vic - I don't know of any silver bullet that grails offers you in terms of performing clone/deep copy.  You're basically stuck writing the deep copy logic yourself either in Groovy or SQL; depending on your application one will probably be a better option than the other.

Comment: @vic - don't mistake asking for more information a summary judgment that you're "doing it wrong."  You seem hesitant to describe your real problem, perhaps you're under an NDA or just aren't comfortable divulging your intellectual property.  I have no problem with that, but the example you used has problems.  i.e. in a database you wouldn't want to have multiple records for the same employee.  You update one record of the employee and not the other you now don't know which one to believe.  This is a data anomaly and by definition your data are no longer normalized. (continued...)

Comment: (continued...) There are times when you need a deep copy operation or some kind of default initialization.  For example, maybe you are writing wiki software where you want to create a new space as a copy of some default space.  In that kind of situation deep copy is not such a bad option, things are truly independent.  In your department example where you're copying 'Billy Bob' that's got data integrity problems written all over it.  So please forgive me if I gave you the impression you were doing something wrong.  I was really just trying to understand your problem better.

Comment: @prolux, you are right, my example sucks; your example of a wiki is much more appropriate to what I'm asking. At the heart of my question is, given that you *need* to do a deep copy on the database, how do you do it efficiently for best performance? My contrived example was just fodder for answering in a digestible context. My real case is way too complicated to diagram out, that's all...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done a similar thing using [INSERT INTO ... SELECT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-select.html) syntax. (The C api also has a MYSQL_OPTION_MULTI_STATEMENTS_ON which you can use to run multiple statements with. or you could use a procedure).

This is the most effective, since you do not have to move data between the client and the server. The value copied was a template to create a new entity. I don't understand why you are doing this with this particiluar data model.