# string manipulation with objective-c

Tags: cocoa

I have a string like this
a web url

"https://stackoverflow.com/questions/**3260091**/databases-and-deep-copy"

how can i get the second to last section of the url?

**3260091**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3260091/databases-and-deep-copy"];  //or however you get this url

NSString * path = [url path];
NSArray * components = [path pathComponents];

NSString * questionID = [components objectAtIndex:[components count]-2];
```

Comment: In OS 10.6 or later, you can send a `pathComponents` message directly to the `NSURL`, without converting to `NSString`.

Comment: @JWWalker very true.  I've been spending all of my time in 10.5-land :)